# How to compile vector from cpp in cython?

Tags: cython

I try to use `vector` data type in `cython`.

cy_test.pyx

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="cy_test", ext_modules=cythonize("cy_test.pyx", compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"}))
```

terminal

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

The output is:

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\cython\sandbox>python setup.py build_ext -i
Compiling cy_test.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing cy_test.pyx
cy_test.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\yvals_
core.h(28): STL1003: Unexpected compiler, expected C++ compiler.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\yvals_
core.h(29): fatal error C1189: #error:  Error in C++ Standard Library usage
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14
.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I tried to:

- google the error message and possibly the issues is with the version of the MSVC
- reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools

I have these ones installed:

[image]

I expected that the program will compile without errors.

Comment: You haven't asked for it to be compiled as C++, so it's being compiled as C